# Linked list merge sort using java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

I want to implement merge sort just with linked list without any array, using java. But i got stuck in a logical error; my code eliminates some inputs and sorts the remains. I have applied three class: `Divide` , `Merg` , `MergSort` as below:

```
public class Divide {

    List firstList = new List();
    List secondList = new List();

    public int GetLength(List list) {
        int Length = 0;
        Link temp = new Link();
        temp.next = list.head.next;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            Length++;
        }

        return Length;
    }

    public List rightSide(List list) {
        int Length = GetLength(list);
        Link temp = new Link();
        temp.next = list.head.next;

            for (int i = 1; i <= Math.floor(Length / 2); i++) {
                firstList.Insert(temp.next.data);
                temp.next = temp.next.next;
            }
            return firstList;
    }

    public List leftSide(List list) {
        int Length = GetLength(list);
        Link temp = new Link();
        temp.prev = list.head.prev;

            for (int i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(Length / 2); i++) {
                secondList.Insert( temp.prev.data);
                temp.prev =  temp.prev.prev;
            }
            return secondList;
        }
    }
```

merge:

```
public class Merg {

    public List MergedList = new List();
    private  List Temp = new List();

    public List Merg (List one, List two)
    {
        Link onelink = new Link();
        Link twolink = new Link();

        onelink.next = one.head.next;
        twolink.next = two.head.next;

        while (onelink.next!= null || twolink.next!= null)
        {

            if(onelink.next!= null && twolink.next != null)
            {
              if(onelink.next.data < twolink.next.data)
              {
                  Temp.Insert(onelink.next.data);
                  onelink.next = onelink.next.next;
              }
              else
              {
                  Temp.Insert(twolink.next.data);
                  twolink.next = twolink.next.next;
              }

            }

            if (onelink.next != null && twolink.next == null)
            {
                Temp.Insert(onelink.next.data);
                onelink.next = onelink.next.next;
            }
            if (twolink.next != null && onelink.next == null)
            {
                Temp.Insert(twolink.next.data);
                twolink.next = twolink.next.next;
            }

        }

        if (Temp.head.next.data > Temp.head.prev.data)
        {
            while (Temp.head.next != null)
            {
                MergedList.Insert(Temp.head.next.data);
                Temp.head.next = Temp.head.next.next;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MergedList.head.next = Temp.head.next;
        }


        return MergedList;
    }

}
```

MergSort:

```
public class MergSort {

    public List mergSort (List list)
    {
        Divide divide = new Divide();
        Merg merg = new Merg();

        if (divide.GetLength(list) > 1) {
            return merg.Merg(mergSort(divide.leftSide(list)), mergSort(divide.rightSide(list)));
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Although i have wrote the `link` and `list` classes too, but i think there is no trouble in there. (However if it was necessary i will mention them)
Now, when i import some inputs such that : {100,3,1,7,6} the Output is: 3,6,7,100. (1 has been eliminated!) or another example: {100,3,1} the output is: 1,100 (where is 3??)

I wonder if someone can help me...

Link:

```
public class Link {
    public double data;
    public Link prev;
    public Link next;
}
```

list:

```
public class List {
    public Link head = new Link();

    public void setHead(Link head) {
        this.head = head;
        head.prev = null;
        head.next = null;
    }

    public void Insert(double x)
    {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.data = x;
        if (head.next == null)
        {
            head.next = link;
            head.prev = link;
        }
        else
        {
            head.next.prev = link;
            link.next = head.next;
            head.next = link;
        }
    }

    public Link delete()
    {
        Link temp = new Link();
        temp = head;
        head = head.next;
        return temp;
    }

    public Link search(double x)
    {
        Link link = new Link();
        link.next = head;
        while (link.next.data != x)
        {
            link.next = link.next.prev;
        }

        return link.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your code please. It will show you what's happening step by step.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it using the debugger? And why do you have different classes for `divide` and `merge`? Isn't that a bit too complicated?

Comment: Where is the link and list classes ?

Comment: Your `Merg` class only checks for `onelink.next.data < twolink.next.data` (and vice-versa) - what if they are equal?

Comment: @Prasath I'v wrote them but really do you think may the trouble was in there? i mean that there is no suspected case in the other classes? if so i edit my post and add them...

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon ...so if the these two values is equal the `else` for `onelink.next.data < twolink.next.data` covers this condition.

Comment: @Shahab_HK No, I have compilation error. That's why asked those files. Without those files I cannot debug in my system.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet 
Frankly im beginner to InteliJ idea and my debugger window doesn't shows nothing. I think there is a trouble in it's configuration and i don't learn the basics of debugging with InteliJ yet...

Comment: @Prasath I added these two classes...and thanks for you helping!

Comment: In lack of a working debugger you may stick in `System.out.println();` statements that show the state of the computation so you can compare with the expected (only remember to remove them afterwards).

Comment: @Shahab_HK. Got those files. Let me check.

Comment: How you are running your code? I created new List() object and then inserted all the numbers. After that applied mergSort with that list. That mergSort returns result. where and how you are checking the result ?

Comment: @Prasath I run just with a while loop as below:

`Link temp = new Link();
        temp.next = mergSort.mergSort(list1).head.next;
        while (temp.next != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.next.data);
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
        }` (list1 is list of inputs.) 
why my results is deterrent with you???
now i test with your manner.

Comment: @Prasath No, i tested your method and there was no difference in results compare with my mentioned code in previous comment...

Comment: @Shahab_HK - I deleted my answer, because your insert method for a null terminate list is OK. You may be interested in a bottom up merge sort approach, but that needs a small (25 to 32) array of references to nodes (the array replaces the log2(n) references pushed onto the stack by a top down approach). Here is a link to [Wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged a lot but I can't make sense of your `Divide` class. You don't need it at all.

```
public class MergSort {

    public List mergSort(List list) {
        Divide divide = new Divide();
        Merg merg = new Merg();
        int n = list.getLength();
        if (n > 1) {
//            return merg.Merg(mergSort(divide.leftSide(list)), mergSort(divide.rightSide(list)));
            Link cursor = list.head.next;
            List left = new List();
            List right = new List();
            // for (i = 0; ....... i will be 0 if head is not dummy
            for (int i = 1; cursor != null; i++) {
                if (i <= n/2)
                    left.Insert(cursor.data);
                else
                    right.Insert(cursor.data);
                cursor = cursor.next;
            }
            left = mergSort(left);
            right = mergSort(right);

            return merg.Merg(left, right);

        } else {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a `getLength()` method in your `List` class. It should be in `List` class because you want the length of your list.

```
public int getLength() {
    int Length = 0;
    Link temp = head.next;
    while (temp != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
        Length++;
    }

    return Length;
}
```

Also, rename your `Link` class to `Node`. Because a `Link` means a **link** between to objects or an edge between nodes. What you really want is a `Node`. It's confusing.

In your `List` class, you have defined `head` like this:

```
public Link head = new Link();
```

I don't see why you would need a [dummy headed linked list](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~cs351/linked-list-variations.html).

A linked list with a dummy head is basically a head with no values and hence dummy.

[image]

Because of your dummy head, you are starting your for loops in `Divide` class from `i = 1`. Why complicate things? If you really need a dummy head, then keep it or define it like this:

```
public Link head;
// don't instantiate the head. It's just a reference
```

Also, you seem to create a half-circular linked list. What I mean by that is that the `head.prev` points to the last link/node in the list. If you truly want a circular linked list then point your `tail.next` to head.

Here is what a circular linked list looks like:

[image]

Or if you don't want a circular list, then don't point your `head.prev` to the last object.

In your `Insert()` method in `List.java`:

```
if (head.next == null)
{
    head.next = link;
    // remove head.prev = link;
}
```

Comment: In the case of a double linked list with a dummy (aka sentinel or head) node, then dummy.prev points to the last node in the list, and as you mentioned, dummy.prev.next (last node.next) points to dummy.

Comment: @rcgldr Conventionally, a double linked list with a dummy head has head.prev set to null.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, I agree with you, but OP here didn't make it fully circular. In OP's implementation, lastNode.next == null. Also, in my previous comment, I was talking about double (but not circular) linked list.

Comment: Thanks for your response! your hints was useful for me.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet - even in the case of a null terminated list, using head.prev to point to last node allows for a fast append, using the dummy node as a container for the head and tail pointers. A sort would need to update head.prev when complete. I agree that a dummy node is not needed for a null terminated linked list. It would make more sense to have a dummy node for a circular list, but even that isn't needed. For a circular list, just a tail reference is needed, as head can be created at anytime using head = tail.next .

Comment: @rcgldr For a circular list, it's also possible to just have a `head`, because we can get tail using `head.prev`. We can still append at the end using this. And yes, reverse is also true (as you said). In OP's merge implementation, he sends back a list with it's `head` updated.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet - All those calls to .insert() are duplicating nodes, consuming space. Seems there should be a method to remove a node from one list and insert to another list via linkage instead of duplicating nodes. Insert breaks stability, using append (to end list) would fix this.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet - In case you're interested, to avoid all that scanning to split lists, it's faster to use a bottom up merge sort approach, with a small (25 to 32) array of references to nodes (the array replaces the log2(n) references pushed onto the stack by a top down approach). The sort operates as if the list is a single linked list, and after the sort, if the list is a doubly linked list, a single pass is made to set the previous pointers in the nodes. Here is a link to [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .